# php array push to start and keep keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array (size=263)
  0 => string 'abend' (length=5)
  1 => string 'andorra' (length=7)
  2 => string 'united_arab_emirates' (length=20)
  3 => string 'afghanistan' (length=11)
  4 => string 'antigua_and_barbuda' (length=19)
  5 => string 'anguilla' (length=8)
  6 => string 'albania' (length=7)
  7 => string 'armenia' (length=7)
  8 => string 'netherlands_antilles' (length=20)
  9 => string 'angola' (length=6)
  10 => string 'antarctica' (length=10)
  11 => string 'american_samoa' (length=14)
  12 => string 'austria' (length=7)
  13 => string 'australia' (length=9)
  14 => string 'aruba' (length=5)
  15 => string 'azerbaijan' (length=10)
  16 => string 'bosnia_and_herzegovina' (length=22)
  17 => string 'barbados' (length=8)
  18 => string 'bangladesh' (length=10)
  19 => string 'belgium' (length=7)
  20 => string 'burkina_faso' (length=12)
  ...
```

this is a list of countries that later is converted to a dropdown...
now I have the user country and I want to remove his country from the list 
BUT
to prepend it to the start so it will be first.

Example:

lets say that the user country is "belgium" so the id of it is 19.
so the new array should be:

```
array (size=263)
  19 => string 'My country' (length=5)
  0 => string 'abend' (length=5)
  1 => string 'andorra' (length=7)
  2 => string 'united_arab_emirates' (length=20)
  3 => string 'afghanistan' (length=11)
  4 => string 'antigua_and_barbuda' (length=19)
  5 => string 'anguilla' (length=8)
  6 => string 'albania' (length=7)
  7 => string 'armenia' (length=7)
  8 => string 'netherlands_antilles' (length=20)
  9 => string 'angola' (length=6)
  10 => string 'antarctica' (length=10)
  11 => string 'american_samoa' (length=14)
  12 => string 'austria' (length=7)
  13 => string 'australia' (length=9)
  14 => string 'aruba' (length=5)
  15 => string 'azerbaijan' (length=10)
  16 => string 'bosnia_and_herzegovina' (length=22)
  17 => string 'barbados' (length=8)
  18 => string 'bangladesh' (length=10)
  20 => string 'burkina_faso' (length=12)
  ...
```

As you can see belgium was erased from the array, and "my country" was added to the top.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: You cannot change order of numeric keys in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

since you know the user country unset it from the initial array, while keeping the user country in another array, then you can combine it to form the new array.

```
$first = array(1 => brazil, 2 => china, 3 => germany);
$second = array(3 => germany);
unset($ss[3]);
$combine = $first + $second;
print_r($combine);
```

result:

Array
(
    [3] => germany
    [1] => brazil
    [2] => china
)

Answer (score 0):

for achieving this you need a collection interface upon array or a truly collection thing in php . i suggest check this out
[collection classes in php - sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/collection-classes-in-php/)